# Laravel how to set locale for __() helper without it using the app locale

Tags: laravel, localization

I need to retrieve localized strings from Laravel's language files in a locale of my choosing without it automatically using the app's set locale.

Normally I use the __() helper for getting language files but this doesn't have a way of setting the locale.

Is there a function that allows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I only find the answer AFTER posting the question. Even after googling it and going through the documentation for a good half hour...

Apparently the Lang::get() function accepts a third parameter for locale.

Comment: `function __($key = null, $replace = [], $locale = null)`